# getting the x number of multiple images being uploaded in firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I currently have a working code for storing the local images, uploading it in firestore storage and writing it on cloud firestore. It's all working now. However I am working with the UI for indicators.
I want the user to see how many of their images have been uploaded for example "uploaded 1 out of 10 of images". I can't see a similar logic or maybe i do not have any clue on how to do it, any ideas are greatly appreciated.

```
Future uploadImage() async {
    String catchUrls;
    // loop, reiterate the files stored in List<XFile> imageFileList
    for (var image in imageFileList!) {
      // create new file name
      String uniqueFileName = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
      // get current file name
      String currentFileName = image.path;
      // replace with new file na,e
      String newFileName =
          currentFileName.replaceAll(currentFileName, uniqueFileName);
      // reference the location of file.
      Reference reference =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("images").child(newFileName);
      // upload file
      await reference.putFile(File(image.path));
      // get the download urls
      catchUrls = await reference.getDownloadURL();
      // store the download urls to the List<String>getDownloadUrls.
      getDownloadUrls.add(catchUrls);
      print(getDownloadUrls);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StreamController` like following:

```
 StreamController<int> streamController = StreamController();

 Future uploadImage() async {
    String catchUrls;
    // loop, reiterate the files stored in List<XFile> imageFileList
    for (var image in imageFileList!) {
      // create new file name
      String uniqueFileName = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
      // get current file name
      String currentFileName = image.path;
      // replace with new file na,e
      String newFileName =
          currentFileName.replaceAll(currentFileName, uniqueFileName);
      // reference the location of file.
      Reference reference =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("images").child(newFileName);
      // upload file
      await reference.putFile(File(image.path));
      // get the download urls
      catchUrls = await reference.getDownloadURL();
      // store the download urls to the List<String>getDownloadUrls.
      getDownloadUrls.add(catchUrls);
      streamController.add(getDownloadUrl.length);
      print(getDownloadUrls);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Hello'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await uploadImage();
              },
              child: const Text('Upload Images'),
            ),
            StreamBuilder<int>(
              stream: streamController.stream,
              initialData: 0,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text(
                      'uploaded ${snapshot.data} out of ${imagesFileList.length} of images');
                }
                return Text('Waiting...');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here at every iteration of adding image to FirebaseStorage you are adding length of `getDownloadedUrl` to the stream. And in `StreamBuilder` you are getting that length.

Comment: Thanks man, it really helped me a lot. Thank you for the explanation as well, it helped me to understand the logic about it!